# Loading Retrieving data as well as the search in using datatable

Tags: php, codeigniter, datatable, serverside-javascript

Model:

```
public function get_adjustment($group_id, $start, $length, $search, $order_by, $order_dir)
    {
        $this->db->select('uni.inv_id, batch.batch_id, uni.item_code, des.design_name, cat.cat_type, supply.item_size, des.gender_status, uni.quantity, batch.b_remain_qty, batch.batch_code');
        $this->db->from('ebs.uni_inventory uni');
        $this->db->join('ebs.uni_batch batch', 'batch.group_id = uni.group_id AND batch.item_code = uni.item_code', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('ebs.uni_stocksupply_v2 supply', 'supply.item_type = uni.item_type AND supply.item_design = uni.item_design AND supply.item_code = uni.item_code AND supply.item_code = batch.item_code', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('ebs.uni_stockdesign_v2 des', 'des.design_type = uni.item_type AND des.design_id = uni.item_design', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('ebs.uni_stockcategory_v2 cat', 'cat.stock_id = uni.item_type', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('uni.status', 'active');
        $this->db->where('uni.group_id', $group_id);
        $this->db->order_by($order_by, $order_dir);
        $this->db->limit($length, $start);

        if (!empty($search)) {
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->like('uni.item_code', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('des.design_name', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('cat.cat_type', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('supply.item_size', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('des.gender_status', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('uni.quantity', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('batch.b_remain_qty', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('batch.batch_code', $search);
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        $result = $this->db->get();
        return $result->result_array();
    }

    public function getTotalRecords($group_id, $search)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('ebs.uni_inventory uni');
        $this->db->join('ebs.uni_batch batch', 'batch.group_id = uni.group_id AND batch.item_code = uni.item_code', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('ebs.uni_stocksupply_v2 supply', 'supply.item_type = uni.item_type AND supply.item_design = uni.item_design AND supply.item_code = uni.item_code AND supply.item_code = batch.item_code', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('ebs.uni_stockdesign_v2 des', 'des.design_type = uni.item_type AND des.design_id = uni.item_design', 'inner');
        $this->db->join('ebs.uni_stockcategory_v2 cat', 'cat.stock_id = uni.item_type', 'inner');
        $this->db->where('uni.status', 'active');
        $this->db->where('uni.group_id', $group_id);

        // $this->db->where('uni.quantity != batch.b_remain_qty');

        if (!empty($search)) {
            $this->db->group_start();
            $this->db->like('uni.item_code', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('des.design_name', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('cat.cat_type', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('supply.item_size', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('des.gender_status', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('uni.quantity', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('batch.b_remain_qty', $search);
            $this->db->or_like('batch.batch_code', $search);
            $this->db->group_end();
        }
        // return $this->db->get()->row()->total_records;
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return count($query->result_array());

    }...............
}
```

Controller:

```
public function get_inventory_data()
{
    $group_id   = $this->input->post('group_id');
    $start      = $this->input->post('start');
    $length     = $this->input->post('length');
    $search     = $this->input->post('search')['value'];
    // $column     = $this->input->post('order')[0]['column'];
    // $order_dir  = $this->input->post('order')[0]['dir'];

    // $columns = ['inv_id', 'batch_id', 'item_code', 'design_name', 'cat_type', 'item_size', 'gender_status', 'quantity', 'b_remain_qty'];
    // $order_by = $columns[$column];
    $order_by   = $this->input->post('columns')[$this->input->post('order')[0]['column']]['data'];
    $order_dir  = $this->input->post('order')[0]['dir'];

    $columns = ['inv_id', 'batch_id', 'item_code', 'design_name', 'cat_type', 'item_size', 'gender_status', 'quantity', 'b_remain_qty'];

    if (empty($order_by) || !in_array($order_by, $columns)) {
        $order_by = $columns[0];
    }

    $data = $this->AdjustmentModel->get_adjustment($group_id, $start, $length, $search, $order_by, $order_dir);

    $totalRecords = $this->AdjustmentModel->getTotalRecords($group_id, $search);

    $data_output = array(
        'draw' => intval($this->input->post('draw')),
        'recordsTotal' => intval($totalRecords),
        'recordsFiltered' => intval($totalRecords),
        'data' => $data,
    );

    echo json_encode($data_output);
}
```

I Want to get the data fast and load data when search fast.......helpp

Comment: Why select all columns from 5 tables when you just want the `num_rows()`?  Do you want `count_all_results()`?  Are your tables well-indexed in the database?

Comment: yes it is, the data is retrieved already but when performing search in using datatable is quite slow that it takes 30s to load even the searched data more or less 4

Comment: Does your dataTable object have `serverSide: true, /** IMPORTANT: this means that every sorting click makes a trip to the db; this is recommended for DataTables that might have hundreds of thousands of rows */` ? Can we see the dataTable object settings?  I have a project that joins 15 tables for a massive search page -- some of those tables have hundreds of thousands of rows.  You aren't passing every row back to your dataTable in that json string, right? Your are running a decidedly greedy/hungry multi-LIKE query there -- that's probably a point of concern.

Comment: `getTotalRecords()` returns a `count()` value which means it will always be an integer -- `intval()` in your controller is not necessary.  `get_adjustment()` should be camelCased `getAdjustment()` and its return type should be explicitly hinted as `array` because `result_array()` only returns an array.